# How to import list of zip codes per metro with ImportXML

Tags: google-sheets-formula, zipcode

I'm trying to import a list of zip codes by metro area from StatisticalAtlas.com (ex. https://statisticalatlas.com/metro-area/Michigan/Marquette/Overview) but am having trouble getting the =IMPORTXML feature to scrape any information.

It looks like the zip code section on the metro area pages from [StatisticalAtlas](https://statisticalatlas.com/metro-area/Michigan/Marquette/Overview) isn't coded in JavaScript (I could be wrong).

Let me know if you have any suggestions that may work but this is the formula I am currently using in Sheets: `=IMPORTXML H2, '//*[@id="top"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[6]/div[8]/div[2])'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://statisticalatlas.com/metro-area/Michigan/Marquette/Overview","//*[@id='top']/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[6]/div[8]/div[2]/div")
```

To extract the zip codes and clean it all up, use:

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML("https://statisticalatlas.com/metro-area/Michigan/Marquette/Overview","//*[@id='top']/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[6]/div[8]/div[2]/div")),", ","")),"Select * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")
```

Starting at the basics **IMPORTXML** brings the zip codes over horizontally as formatted on the website.

We then **TRANSPOSE** the data to align vertically (remove if you want them horizontally).

Next we **SUBSTITUTE** out the comma delimiters with empty strings.

**ARRAYFORMULA** ensures we obtain the entire array of zip codes.

**QUERY** finally filters out NULL values (previously the comma's).